# Complex joins in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table of itineraries. An itinerary belongs to a customer and has multiple days. A package is assigned to each of these days. I want to be able to produce a manifest showing which customers are allocated to a package and on which days.

I'm struggling with Eloquent, because you can't do queries beyond a one-to-Many relationship

What i want to do is this:

`return $this->package->where('PackageID, $id)->itineraryDay->itinerary->customer->select('CustomerID', 'Date')`

But can only really achieve it using the query builder:

`return DB::connection($this->connection)
            ->table('t_package as PA')
            ->join('t_itinerary_day_map as IDM', 'IDM.PackageID', '=', 'PA.PackageID')
            ->join('t_itinerary_day as ID', 'IDM.ItineraryDayID', '=', 'ID.ItineraryDayID')
            ->join('t_itinerary as IT', 'IT.ItineraryID', '=', 'ID.ItineraryID')
            ->join('t_customer as CC', 'CC.ItineraryID', '=', 'IT.ItineraryID')
            ->where('PA.PackageID', $id)
            ->select('CC.CustomerID', 'ID.Date')
            ->distinct()
            ->get();`

I really want to use Eloquent as I hate hardcoding table names and i've already created relationships for these models, but can't see any way around it

Comment: You're not making any `where` clauses for your relations. Do you just want to fetch the relations for a package by ID?

Comment: Yep, but because a package can be used on many different itinerary days, Laravel won't let you chain relationships beyond this. It wants you to loop through all the days and then get the itineraries for each of those days. I just want an array of customers returned (I missed out the mapping table relationship which is many to many)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do something like this to find customers that have a package with the given ID:

```
$packageId = 42;
$customers = $customer->whereHas('packages', function($q) use($packageId){ 
    return $q->where('package_id', $packageId); 
})->get();
```

How would that work for what you want?

Comment: I think my issue is because the chain of relationships always use Has, until it gets to the mapping table, where the days belongTo, so the clause goes down the chain, then has to try and traverse back up. Going the $customer route fails because Customer belongsTo Itinerary

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to make few assumptions on your relationship but it seems doable.

> If one ItineraryDay belongs to one Itinerary. And one Itinerary belongs to one Customer. And one ItineraryDay may have more than one Package.

```
$packageID = 111;
$itineraryDays = ItineraryDay::with('itinerary.customer')
                                ->whereHas('package', function($q) use($packageID) {
                                    $q->where('PackageID', $packageID);
                                })
                                ->get();

foreach($itineraryDays as $itineraryDay) {
    var_dump($itineraryDay);
    var_dump($itineraryDay->itinerary->customer);
}
```

I'm not sure if i get your relationship method naming correct, but hopefully this works.